1 minute delay query to GraphQL / Neo4j on EKS
I am running an app on AWS EKS. I have 3 separate pods for each API (graphql), app(react) and neo4j, a total of 9. Normally queries take 1-2 secs to respond but sometimes there is a 1-minute delay, so some requests take 1 min and 2 secs. How can I investigate and find out where the issue might be? I tried logs for all and nothing useful.
The only lead I have is Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1719330740381, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]" but looked into the routing table for neo4j and looks good.
Any ideas, please?
Thanks,
Dragos
